# How to get path of currently open file in Windows 7 in any application

Tags: windows-7, path

Is it possible to get the path of the currently open file (path on local disk or network path UNC) in the frontmost window in `Microsoft Windows 7`?

If it would be possible *at least* for `Microsoft Office 2007` applications, this would be great, but a system wide function would be great.

(a solution for `MacOS X` is described here: [Get path of open file in any application on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/295963/get-path-of-open-file-in-any-application-on-mac-os-x))

Answer (score 1):

The best you could probably do is look at the recent documentation registry keys, and get the list of most recent documents.

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RecentDocs
```

However, this isn't going to show you whether a document is currently open or not. You could potentially check the title of all open applications, since many applications put document names in their window titles, but this is not a requirement, and many applications do not do that.

Answer (score 1):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) can display all open files for each process. Select View/Show Lower Pane and View/Lower Pane View/Handles, then select the process.

However, it is not possible to see directly which of the files is the one "open".